# Sails js , How to send events in background to mobile

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, mobile, sails.js

Hi we are developing mobile app and want to sent some event triggers to mobile form sails js to mobile . We have rest services exposed over sails which mobile is consuming. Is it possible to send some events to mobile from sails and android application do some processing on getting those events..

Answer (score 0):

Yes..!! You can use **Push Notifications** Or **Cron Job** Or **Node-Schedular**

There is a  npm package called "sails-service-pusher" for push notifications and

"node-schedule" for cron job.

For Background jobs You can use Cron Job.

That's the best way to trigger a events in background.